# how to make a weapon shatter when hit

Tags: animation, effects

I am animating a fight between two characters and I ran into a scene where I wanted one of the character's weapons to shatter like glass when the other character slices it.
 I have used a few things that supposedly do this including the cell fracture add-on but it did never finishes they top part of the sword , but the methods I've found do not work with a sword such as a katana.

I'm hoping for a way to either make the cell fracture work or find another way to break the object like glass.

here is what happens when i try to use the cell fracture on the katana:

[image]

Here is the original katana in edit mode:

[image]

Comment: have you tried the cell fracture addon?

Comment: Could you please specify what 'it does not work' means? It's unclear at the moment what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: there is a youtube tutorial series here on how to shatter a coffee cup, it might be a similar effect to what you're trying: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=shattering+a+coffee+cup+-+part+01+ The special thing is, they use the Grease Pencil to define the shard distribution, so there's a lot of control for the shatter effect.

Comment: How realistic should it be? Katanas seem to break like this: http://www.thesamuraiworkshop.com/university/images/ive-damaged-the-edge-of-my-sword/two-pieces.jpg

Comment: add more detail as to how the cell fracture is not working

Comment: What does the object look like (in edit mode to see the geometry) before cell fracture? Or are you able to [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) the .blend?

Comment: i actually hought about that too and checked the object for any geometry problems and i did find one however it did not fix the problem

Comment: It's possible that the object is lacking enough geometry for cell fracture to work properly, and that's why the blade looks the way it does in the image above. But without seeing the object before the fracture or looking at the file, it's just a guess.

Comment: Cell fracture may create result like that when the original mesh is non-manifold. Enter Edit mode, choose either Vertex or Edge selection mode and run `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`M`. If something is selected most liklely it's the problem.

Comment: @MrZak ...You need to post your comments as answers. If you did that, more than half of the unanswered questions would be solved lol. If you don't, I will put the answer as community wiki.

Comment: @10Replies  Oh well I've already forgot about this one. I wanted to elaborate as soon as I get OP's answer if that helped. Didn't think the answer is really helpful but will add. You can post answers as well, but please elaborate a bit in them about the issue to make them clearer as when I post comments they aren't intended to be answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cell Fracture](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Fracture) addon can create sometimes results with parts not cut out. One possible reason for that is [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry); as long as mesh will be non-manifold it won't be broken well enough by the addon. You can test that with default monkey (as it's non-manifold because of the eyes):

[image: screenshot of fractured monkey]

The areas which have unfinished fractures are ones near the eyes and this is one way to determine where non-manifold geometry is present. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to make non-manifold parts selected, [Mesh Lint](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/MeshLint) addon and others. There are some certain techniques used for repairing such areas listed in the linked answers.

Comment: i actually fixed it a while ago but thanks